# Is there a MongoDB to MySQL adapter

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a Javascript library ([SincIt](http://forbesmyester.github.io/SyncIt/index.html)) that I would like to use to synchronise my WebApp with a MySQL Database. However, this SincIt only works with MongoDB at the moment.

I could probably write an MySQL adapter for SincIt, since the library is modular, but I wonder if there is an adapter that translates MongoDB instructions to SQL.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't exist is because their two entirely different solutions. You might have MySQL -> MongoDB but Mongo (schemaless) to MySQL (Schema) would require to know too much about the application itself. Just install mongo, it's not that hard.

Comment: Using Mongo is not an option, because we need to integrate with already existing system that uses MySQL. In our project, this is not negotiable.

Btw. I don't think the question deserver a downvote. In Science, it is also a good research if you find out that something can not work the way you thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is a relational database and uses SQL for manipulation of relational algebra.  MongoDB is a document database that doesn't support relations or joins.

It does allow for hierarchical nesting of documents, but it's simply an entirely different paradigm.

The most important distinction in this case, is that MongoDB is schema-less.  With a mongo collection you never need to do the equivalent of a "CREATE TABLE" statement.  Furthermore, mongo has no problem with you starting with one document with a specific json structure, and then adding additional documents to that collection with entirely different structures.

As Mongo works with json data, you would also have the problem with a relational database of needing to convert table data to json documents and vice versa, which really isn't possible in any generic sense.

With MySQL you of course have to have table structures that are maintained in the data dictionary, and if anything changes you need to ALTER the table.  You could probably implement a generic table structure of rows where the entire data store would be in a blob, stored in the same json format that Sinclt expects, but at that point you might as well just use mongo.

With that said, if there's some business rule that necessitates it, the fastest way to get it working with MySQL would probably be to do what I just suggested and have a generic row structure with something like:

```
id
optype (set, update, delete?)
data (blob storing the json payload)
parent_id
```

Just from a quick perusal of the SincIt docs it appears you'd need something to support the "linked list" aspect of the system.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I have to bind to already defined database structure, so generic tables are also not the option. I guess I will have to write the SyncIt adapter for MySQL after all.